# Twitter Bootstrap css not working in print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

This is aduplicate question, but as I am unable to get solution from the previous threads, so I am asking it again.

Styling how it looks in browser:
[image: Styling how it looks in browser:]

How it looks in print preview
[image: How it looks in print preview]

Why bootstrap css not working in print.

I've tried following so far:

```
    <link href="../bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    AND
    <link href="../bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
    AND
    <link href="../bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/>
```

Do I need to write a seperate print.css which will incorporate all the bootstrap styling used in the page, like col-lg-6, bg-danger.. and so on.

**Check this** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drwsu8jf/1/)

Comment: Have a look at this. http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/05/printing-with-bootstrap.html

Comment: You DON'T need to include any `media` attribute. We'll need to see your full HTML and custom CSS to be able to debug this. Can't debug a screenshot without seeing the code behind it.

Comment: @cvrebert : check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drwsu8jf/1/